# Is 1 Corinthians 13:9-12 a literary structure?

Tags: 1-corinthians, pauline-epistles, literary-structure

KJV 1 Corinthians 13 : 9 - 12

> For we know in part, and we prophesy in part.10 But when that which is perfect is come, then that which is in part shall be done away. 11 When I was a child, I spake as a child, I understood as a child, I thought as a child: but when I became a man, I put away childish things. 12 For now we see through a glass, darkly; but then face to face: now I know in part; but then shall I know even as also I am known.

There seems to be some form of structure in the way these texts are laid out

A) 9 For we know in part,
and we prophesy in part.(Partly)

B) 10 But when that which is perfect is come,then that which is in part shall be done away.(Fully)

A) 11 When I was a child, I spake as a child,I understood as a child, I thought as a child:(Partly)

B) but when I became a man, I put away childish things.(Fully)

A) 12 For now we see through a glass, darkly;(Partly)

B) but then face to face:(Fully)

A) now I know in part(Partly)

B) but then shall I know even as also I am known.(Fully)

I have recontructed the above texts trying to find some form of a literary structure.I'm not sure whether there is a structure or not but thought there was some form of pattern in the above texts

Is there any form of literary structure in the above texts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The passage has structure, and it is literary, but that is not the same as conforming to any formal literary structure recognised in academic language circles. To look for that in biblical passages is a bit like putting the cart before the horse. The various Bible books were written under the inspiration of the Holy Spirit, and not with a desire by the so-guided writers to conform to literary structures. However, given that the Psalms do, indeed, display poetic structure connected to the Hebrew letters of the alphabet, there are examples of literary structure in the Bible, but what Paul wrote here was not formal poetry.

He wrote logically, and in a way that supported what he had just written in the previous chapters about spiritual gifts, and love. He made use of contrasts, to make his point. Your (A) (B) lists are correct, but do not necessarily indicate Paul using a known literary structure.

There's no need to try to find some form of literary structure, for even if that did underpin the text, that would not enhance any understanding and appreciation of the verses in question. It is the spiritual truth of what is being pointed out by Paul that matters.

Answer (score 2):

I do not see any literary structure except for four contrasts in 1 Cor 13:9-12.  These are (with my very literal translation):

| No. | Present world | Futire world |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | V9: in part we know, in part we prophesy | V10: however, when should come the perfect/complete, the in-part will be done away |
| 2 | V11a: when I was a child I was speaking as a child, I was thinking as a child I was reasoning as a child | V11b: when I became a man I did away with things of the child |
| 3 | V12a: for we see presently through a glass obscurely | V12b: however, then face to face |
| 4 | V12c: presently I know in part | V12d: then I will know fully also as I am fully known |

Thus, Paul is attempting to contrast the present imperfect world and its understanding of spiritual truths and action with the future perfect world where secrets and understanding will be vastly improved.